# Outlook ContactItem: get containing folder?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, contactitem

I am maintaining an Outlook add in that manages Outlook contacts.  I have a function that gets all the contacts in a folder and its subfolders.  Now, I need to determine which folder a given contact was retrieved from.  Is this possible without scanning each of the folders or returning the paths along with each of the contact items?

Comment: it is. you have to cast the contact as another type (sorry, i forget which one) and then you can get the folder info.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
public string GetFolderFullName(Outlook.ContactItem ci) {
    Outlook.MAPIFolder mf = ci.Parent;
    string path = mf.FolderPath;
    return path;
}
```